# "Manual" customizable reference text

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing

For a document I am writing, I am considering a table indexed by references to positions in the text with a description of each item.

I know already that I can create a phantom section, and make a reference to it ([here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing)), but then all references appear with the same identifier "section x.x".

Is there any way to customize the reference's text so that I can differentiate the indexes in my table without having to create an independent subsection for each?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example of how far you've gotten in trying to get this to work?

Comment: A minimal example just requires to define \phantomsection\label{mylabel} somewhere, and then I would like to do something as \nameref{mylabel}[my label text], if it existed. Either \autoref, \nameref, \ref or the likes do not give customization power to control the reference's text manually.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish. Clickable links containing arbitrary text? Would hyperref's `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` do the trick? A minimal example really is needed here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. I would also like to change the color of those specific links, what can be done with: \begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycolor}
\hyperlink{label}{my text}
\endgroup thank you

Answer (score 6):

The `hyperref` package requires what you need (see the [manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.pdf) on page 14), use `\hyperlink{name}{text}` and `\hypertarget{name}{text}`, so for your example:

```
\phantomsection\\hypertarget{link.name}{}
...
\hyperlink{link.name}{really important}
```

will create an invisible link labeled "really important".

Answer (score 1):

Or another approach would be

```
\label{sec:whatevername}
```

and then

```
\hyperref[sec:whatevername]{custom text here}
```